# Which service start or read fstab at start?

Tags: systemd, fstab

I am using wsl2 on windows 10.
My fstab is not being read at start and I must type mount -a to load my fstab.
So I want to know how is it really works ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[systemd-fstab-generator](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fstab-generator.html) is the one responsible for this on systems using systemd.  Mind that WSL2 is not using systemd so I would assume you need to put that command somewhere in a file that does get used during boot. [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk) has a page on mounting using `wsl`.

> Synopsis
>
> ```
> /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-fstab-generator
> ```
>
> Description
>
> `systemd-fstab-generator` is a generator that translates `/etc/fstab` into native systemd units early at boot and when configuration of the system manager is reloaded. This will instantiate mount and swap units as necessary.